# How to create another sidebar to be shown on another page?

Tags: sidebar

I've created my wordpress theme from the default Twenty Eleven theme, and I want to show a different sidebar on a few pages. I found [this tutorial](http://ablereach.com/wordpress/wordpress-add-a-second-widget-ready-sidebar/)
but it really doesn't answer my question.

So, I need a sidebar that is shown on admin panel at widgets page, and it should be at left side of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Codex page for [`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar). In particular, the section that mentions [calling sidebars with other names](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar#Parameters) and the [multiple sidebar section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar#Multi_sidebars).

Answer (score -1):

You could create a page template that calls the sidebar you want like Joseph mentioned. That way you can select which template to use depending on which sidebar is right for the page.

[Creating Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

[Adding Widget areas](http://automattic.com/code/widgets/) will show you how to widgetize the sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

May not be a great, super awesome solution, but I just came across [WooDojo by WooThemes](http://www.woothemes.com/woodojo/). It's like [Jetpack by WordPress.com plugin](http://jetpack.me/).

[WooSidebars](http://www.woothemes.com/woosidebars/) is a part of WooDojo plugin suite. You can download the plugin [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/woothemess3/woo_dojo_products/woosidebars.zip) (I think it requires WooDojo pre-installed).

**What it does...**

With WooSidebars you can override any widgetized area on your WordPress-powered website, displaying different widgets for different screens (a page, a category or search results, for example) without touching a line of code.

- No theme modification required
- Seemless WordPress Integration
- Custom Sidebars for Any Post
- Override any dynamic sidebar
- Advanced Replacement Conditions (different widgets on different pages)

I am only suggesting this plugin because you can be sure that the plugin won't be abandoned like most on WP.org, and the code is not bad at all.

Answer (score -1):

First add this following function to your functions.php,

```
function my_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'      => __( 'Custom Sidebar Widgets' ),
        'id'        => 'custom-sidebar-widgets',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget sidebar-widget custom-sidebar-widgets %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init', 11 );
```

Add this code where you want to fetch custom sidebar,

```
<!-- begin custom sidebar -->
<div id="custom-sidebar">
<ul>
     <?php 
    if ( function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) && dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-widgets' ) ) {
        /* Custom code if dynamic_sidebar not found */
    } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- end sidebar2 -->
```

This code works fine to me.

Comment: `function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' )` is not necessary.